# Find specific number in reference cell and write to new cell

Tags: excel

I have two cells with numbers i.e. `A1` and `B1`. I need a formula to get the digits in `A1` which are present in `B1` to be shown in cell `B2`.

In below example, all digits in `A1` i.e. 5,3,9,4 are found in `B1` and therefore shall be shown in cell `B2`

```
cell A1 = 5394
cell B1 = 7284395
cell B2 = 5394 [formula result]
```

Thank you

[image: The image]

Comment: But from your example `B1` not any match/partial match to `A1` cell content.

Comment: Where is your own attempt at solving this? Be concise and clear about what you have researched/tried so far and what problem you are having solving this on your own. See [ask] a quesiton with a [mcve] and edit your question accordingly. Also include which version of Excel you are using.

Comment: It will be good to mention the version of Excel you are using as well. I have edited your post and hopefully it now makes more sense to the reading person.

Comment: more simple, lets say cell B1 = 12345 and cell A1=5, i want to find that number 5 in A1 if available in B1 then write it down to cell C1

Answer (score 0):

The function below will work but is limited to 4 characters in A1.

```
=IF(AND(ISNUMBER(FIND(MID(A1, 1, 1), B1)), ISNUMBER(FIND(MID(A1, 2, 1), B1)), ISNUMBER(FIND(MID(A1, 3, 1), B1)), ISNUMBER(FIND(MID(A1, 4, 1), B1))), A1, "")
```

This looks at each character in A1 using MID(). It passes that to FIND() to see if that character is in B2. It uses ISNUMBER() around FIND() to see if it's getting a valid numerical result. In this case it's easier than checking for an error. It uses AND() to check that all 4 characters are in B2.

Again, this will work but is not flexible at all regarding the length if the text in A1. You likely want something different. Please share more info about what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

The below code will work. It divides the **SearchTerm** into individual character strings called **SearchTerm_Individual** based on the length of the SearchTerm. The code further appends the individual characters to the result cell, if found in the **SearchIn** String.

```
Option Explicit
Sub Search_Item2()
Dim SearchTerm As String
Dim SearchIn As String
Dim SearchTerm_Length As Integer
Dim X As Byte

    SearchTerm = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value
    SearchIn = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B1").Value

        SearchTerm_Length = Len(SearchTerm)

        Dim SearchTerm_Individual() As String
        ReDim SearchTerm_Individual(1 To SearchTerm_Length) As String

            For X = 1 To SearchTerm_Length
                SearchTerm_Individual(X) = Mid(SearchTerm, X, 1)

                If InStr(SearchIn, SearchTerm_Individual(X)) > 0 Then
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C1").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C1").Value & SearchTerm_Individual(X)
                End If
            Next X
End Sub
```